# Controlling keyboard LEDs using C or C++

Tags: c++, c, keyboard, windows-8.1, led

So I've been trying to program the LEDs on my laptop's keyboard using C or C++ but I haven't gotten too far. There are programs that can change the colors of the LEDs, so I tried to monitor what they do using CheatEngine and see what these programs change but that didn't work either. So what is the easiest way to program each single LED on the keyboard?
Specs:
Windows 8.1
MSI GS60 
SteelSeriesEngine (default program that controls the LEDs)
Thank you.

Comment: This depends on the Keyboard itself. It actually has nothing to do with C/C++

Comment: You could try to find an open source Driver for that Keyboard and look how they did it...

Comment: "Change the colors"? The standard keyboard LEDs are just on/off, you can't change their colors ...

Comment: it's one of these fancy keyboard with colorful LEDs under the buttons

Comment: @ThomasSparber Where can I begin to look for the driver? And if I can't find the driver, can I use some program that already can change the LEDs, and somehow find the address where the values for the LED colors are stored and change it myself?